# Can we use the term independence for a case where something says balls are chosen simultaneously?

Tags: probability, independence

Consider an event of choosing a pair of balls(All the balls in bucket are distinct) from a bucket.

Is it valid to think that sub-events of first ball of pair and second ball of the pair are independent ?

Comment: If the first ball is **not** replaced once the second ball is chosen, then it is not independent.

Comment: No, since if say you have three balls, red, blue, green, picking the green as first ball  of the pair literally means the second ball cannot be green. So, not independent...